# Fake a WebKit browser window's height so that auto-resizing elements respect a certain resolution?

Tags: javascript, html, ios, wkwebview

I'm working with a WKWebView in an iOS development environment which takes a picture of the entire view, by first resizing it to the size of the website it has loaded.

By doing so, this ends up resizing elements that auto-resize depending on window height, such as the video at the top of https://careers.walmart.com. Is there a property I can adjust in the JavaScript console that applies to all (if not most) sites that can trick these elements into resizing based on a fake height value?

I.e if the website is 2000px, and I resize the WebView to that height, the resizable div will also increase to 2000px, pushing the rest of the content below it, and so on. Could I fake the height property so that, for example, regardless of the size of the WebView, the site would think its loaded on a 500px window?

Other alternatives I've found haven't worked properly.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the content in the html shouldnt increase to the size of your webview?

I would use to views, one webViewContainer and another the Wkwebview.
I would statically or dynamically fix the height of the webview or container and use this option in the head of the html body

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, shrink-to-fit=YES" />
```

Here, Im mentioning to take the content equal to device width, and not specifying the height.

the shrink-to-fit = YES will make sure that the html content is fitted into whatever size your webview is.